# Async troubles with layout and loading elements

Tags: javascript, json, graph, cytoscape.js

This is my file graph.json

```
{
"nodes":[                                               
  {"data":{"id": "Node 1"}},
  {"data":{"id": "Node 2"}}                                                 
],                                                  
"edges":[
  {"data":{"source":"Node 1", "target":"Node 2"}}
]
}
```

which I am trying to visualize with cytoscape.js in the CoSE layout using the code below. Unfortunately I only get an empty graph without any nodes. It does work however if I use the 'concentric' or 'grid' layout, or if I write the graph data directly into the cytoscape.js initialization part. Why does it not work the way I did it: with the 'CoSE' layout and a graph loaded from a JSON file?

```
<html>
<head>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cytoscape.github.io/cytoscape.js/api/cytoscape.js-latest/cytoscape.js"></script>

<script>
$(function () {

$('#cy').cytoscape({

    layout: {name: 'cose'},

    style: cytoscape.stylesheet()

    .selector('node')
    .css({'content': 'data(id)'}),

    ready: function () {window.cy = this;}

});

$.getJSON('graph.json', function(data) {cy.load(data)});

});
</script>

</head>

<body>
<div id="cy" style="height: 100%; width: 100%; position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0;">
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) Cytoscape is doing exactly what you're telling it to do.  You initialise with no elements, running CoSE on them.  You load additional elements asynchronously, which will certainly happen after init.

(2) [This blog](http://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/understanding-sync-async-javascript-node/) seems to have a decent description of sync/async.  You may want read a book on JS if you're new to the language or if you're new to programming in general.

(3) If you want to keep things simple, pass a [`fetch`](https://github.com/github/fetch) promise as `options.elements`.  Read the init section for more info: http://js.cytoscape.org/#core/initialisation